# Adding a default header only for POST request

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying a `Typed` `HttpClient` as below. I'm looking to find a way to add `DefaultRequestHeaders` only to my `POST` request (and not to other requests such `GET` or `PUT`). Is there way to achieve this?

Here is my code snippet.

```
var builder = services
     .AddHttpClient("MyService", client =>
      {
         client.BaseAddress = configuration.BaseAddress;

         // Need to default header only for "POST" request                    
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MyHeader", "MyHeaderValue");
      })
      .AddTypedClient<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceRestClient>();
```

I'm trying to find a way where line `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MyHeader", "MyHeaderValue")` is only effective for `POST` request.

Comment: Why not create a seperate service instead?

Answer (score 0):

What about a re-usable *httpclient* that has minimal config and then manage your request by http method specific execution?

For example, consider an async POST method that overrides an internal generic async method that configs the request/response and uses your *httpclient* to execute.  You could pass in the headers you need and/or set the default headers in this method.

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<HttpResponseMessage, T>> PostAsync<T>(Uri uri, object data, AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
{
   return await SendRequestAsync<T, object>(uri.ToString(), data, HttpMethod.Post, authHeader, headers);
}
```

The internal method is as follows:

```
private async Task<KeyValuePair<HttpResponseMessage, T>> SendRequestAsync<T, U>(string requestUri, U content, HttpMethod method, AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = null, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        request.Method = method;
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri, UriKind.Absolute);

        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        if (authHeader != null)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = authHeader;
        }

        string requestContent = null;

        if (content != null)
        {
            requestContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                if (!request.Headers.Contains(header.Key))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        // _client would be a private implementation or injected version of your httpclient
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (response.Content != null)
                {
                    var rawJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var mappedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rawJson);

                    var result = new KeyValuePair<HttpResponseMessage, T>(response, mappedObj);

                    return result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // do something else
            }

            return new KeyValuePair<HttpResponseMessage, T>(response, default(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can certainly do that when calling `SendAsync`, and that's my current implementation as well. But, I was looking for a way to do it when I create `TypedClient` for simplicity..

Comment: Not sure that's doable with the client since that's the vehicle for your request, not the request itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually being stupid here. I realized that I could achieve what I wanted through the `DelegatingHandler`.

```
var builder = services
    .AddHttpClient("MyService", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = configuration.BaseAddress;
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<MySpecialHeaderDelegatingHandler>()
    .AddTypedClient<IMyServiceClient, MyServiceRestClient>();





public class MySpecialHeaderDelegatingHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    private const string MySpecialHeader = "my-special-header";

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        EnsureMySpecialHeaderExists(request);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private static void EnsureMySpecialHeaderExists(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request.Method != HttpMethod.Post) return;

        if (!request.Headers.Contains(MySpecialHeader))
        {
            request.Headers.Add(MySpecialHeader, "MyHeaderValue");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, **DelegatingHandlers** are great, but feels like overkill here.  It interrupts a request that's already in motion just to check the method and add the header.  Why not do that when creating the request?